# Java: How would I obtain a hook/callback of a constructor via reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, constructor, callback, hook

Is it possible to obtain a hook/callback of a constructor via reflection?

My use case is to use expressions as functions. In a language like Kotlin with floating expressions being completely okay combined with extension operators it can make for a truly trivial syntax in some cases.

This cannot be done with a code implementation as the syntax must be entirely boilerplate-free.

Comment: can you show an example?

Comment: @SimoneZandara Essentially this can be used for a function call after object construction, allowing for "operator overloading" on constructors. A really nice example could be hooking constructor of `String` to print to `System.out`, for example `"Hello world!"` would actually print `Hello world!` to the console.

Comment: A more important use case is being able to monitor object construction without an agent.

Answer (score -1):

Java doesn't support operator overloading.

I might be misunderstanding, but from the name of the topic I assume that what you are looking for might be achieved by something like this.

```
public abstract class CustomString {

    protected String wrappedString;

    public CustomString(String string){
        wrappedString = new String(string);
        callback();
    }

    abstract void callback();

    public String toString(){
       return wrappedString;
    }

    abstract void callback();

    }
```

Then extend it to add wanted behaviour.

```
public class CustomStringWithCallback extends CustomString{

public CustomStringWithCallback(String string) {
    super(string);
}

@Override
void callback() {
    System.out.println(wrappedString);
}
```

}

Or simply use anonymous invocation:

```
    new CustomString("some string") {
      @Override
      void callback() {
        System.out.println(wrappedString);   
      }
    };
```

If you need to apply extensions dynamically (at a runtime) you might try applying Decorator pattern to compose various callbacks.

Comment: Java doesn't "support" operator overloading but it's probably possible to emulate such by hooking certain functions. I'm looking for a reflection-based hack to do this on `String` itself.